# Laravel redirects to login after javascript redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, redirect

I have a voting system for models inserted by users. If the model gets 5 votes it gets inserted in the DB. I want to redirect to a general "user submissions" page after successful insert. So if the user casts the 5th vote I redirect to such page. I have a named route that I send to the Ajax request like this:

```
 $redirect_url = route('user_suggested_models');

 $report = ['url' => $redirect_url];

 return Response()->json($report);
```

the route is defined like this:

```
Route::get('model/user_suggested_models', [

    'as' => 'user_suggested_models',

    'middleware' => 'auth',

    'uses' => 'SuggestedModelsController@index'

]);
```

and in the javascript I redirect like this:

```
document.location.href = data.url;
```

So redirect happens but even if I am logged in I get the login page, if I login then it continues the redirect. The problem is that the User is already logged in. Any clue why it wants credentials again?

update:

upgrading to MAMP 4.1 solved the problem entirely without needing to modify the routes.

Answer (score 0):

when you reload page it again calls this url "model/user_suggested_models". since this url is protected by auth it redirects you to login page again.

Comment: is there a way to avoid that? And why it's so? If I reload the same page when logged it won't ask for login since I am already logged in

Comment: try middleware name as auth:web see how that goes.

Comment: can you send me your App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware code

Comment: Your redirect if authentication is fine. 
no there are no implications auth:web means that use middleware auth but use web as guard...web is a default guard that check authentication... :-)

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I didn't modify the stock middleware.

Comment: kindly accept and vote up my answer if my answer worked correctly

Comment: hello again. The problem seems not completely solved. What happens is the first time the user posts and then the page redirects it will redirect to login page. After second login if the user posts again the redirects works without send to login again. Pretty strange. Any idea?